# jQuery.grep : How to filter based on array?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQUery.grep to filer a JSON object. In the here below example I filter the object based on a unique id which is working great :
See : https://jsfiddle.net/zzwcm9cs/18/

```
var arrChildOptions2 = [
        {id:1, name:'john'}, 
        {id:2, name:'mike'},
        {id:3, name:'ben'},
        {id:4, name:'brian'},
    ];

var result = jQuery.grep(arrChildOptions2, function( n, i ) {
  return ( n.id === 2);
});

$( "#result" ).text( JSON.stringify(result) );
```

Now I would like to filter based on an array but I do not really know how to do it. Here below the idea (which of course is not working). The expected result id to have a JSON object only containing "John" and "Ben":

```
var arrChildOptions2 = [
        {id:1, name:'john'}, 
        {id:2, name:'mike'},
        {id:3, name:'ben'},
        {id:4, name:'brian'},
    ];

var myArray = [1,3];

var result = jQuery.grep(arrChildOptions2, function( n, i ) {
  return ( n.id IN myArray);  <<<-- How to do it ?
});

$( "#result" ).text( JSON.stringify(result) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/6ma42602/

```
var arrChildOptions2 = [
        {id:1, name:'john'}, 
        {id:2, name:'mike'},
        {id:3, name:'ben'},
        {id:4, name:'brian'},
    ];
var myArray = [1,3];
var result = jQuery.grep(arrChildOptions2, function( n, i ) {
  //return ( n.id === 2);
  return myArray.indexOf(n.id) > -1;
});

$( "#result" ).text( JSON.stringify(result) );
```